# Compatibility Issue of ASM 3.1 and HIbernate and JAX-RS

Tags: hibernate, jersey, jax-rs, assembly

I have found out that "Hibernate cannot be combined with the reference implementation of JAX-RS." on the link http://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/hibernate-issues/2009-May/015628.html

So i am unable to combine JAX-RS (jersey) with hibernate, does anybody know a work around for this ?

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution to this? I am running into this right now. I am using Hibernate 3.2 Core, Annotations, and Entity Manager. Hibernate dies when I try to add JAX-RS libraries. Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

The root of evil is cglib. Substitute cglib-2.1.3.jar to [cglib-nodep-2.1_3.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/Spring-Related/Downloadcglibnodep213jar.htm) and delete hibernate's asm*.jar files.

Comment: not working for me... getting `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/objectweb/asm/ClassVisitor`

Answer (score 5):

Using *Jersey* (the *Java REST* framework) in conjunction with Hibernate requires some tweaking of Maven's **pom.xml** file. The issue is that Hibernate uses `ASM 1.5.3` which is incompatible with `ASM 3.1` used by *Jersey*.

What you need to do is exclude some transitive dependencies from *Hibernate*:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.6.ga</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm-attrs</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Then, you need to include the correct version of ASM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>asm</groupId>
    <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Finally, you need to include a nodep version of the CGLib which repackages classes from ASM version 1.5.3:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>cglib</groupId>
    <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
    <version>2.1_3</version>
</dependency>
```

source: http://blog.idm.fr/2009/04/jersey-hibernate-conflict.html

Answer (score 3):

Upgrade to a Hibernate 3.3.2 or later.

If you follow the link to the [bug report](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/EJB-358) that message was generated from, it indicates that the latest versions of Hibernate (since 3.3.2) use a different bytecode manipulation package ([Javassist](http://www.csg.is.titech.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/)), which eliminates the conflict over ASM which caused the problem.

Comment: HIbernate 3.3.2 didnt help, i think we still need to instruct hibernate to use javassist in hibernate.properties file, where my project uses hibernate.cfg.xml file, and we cannot enforce javassist in xml file.

Answer (score 3):

***SOLUTION: Compatibility Issue of ASM 3.1 and HIbernate and JAX-RS***

- Remove the following jars
  1 asm-attrs.jar
  2 asm.jar
  3 cglib-2.1.3.jar
- Add the below jar

1 asm-3.1.jar
2 cglib-nodep-2.1_3.jar