# Compatiblity Issue of asm 3.1 and org.eclipse.persistence.asm-2.3.2.jar (jersey-moxy 1.15)

Tags: java, jersey, eclipselink, jax-rs, moxy

A similar problem as in [Compatibility Issue of ASM 3.1 and HIbernate and JAX-RS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/969693/compatibility-issue-of-asm-3-1-and-hibernate-and-jax-rs)
seems to have hit me:
my Jersey / JPA based rest application which also uses jersey-moxy (version 1.15 of jersey) throws an error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.persistence.internal.libraries.asm.ClassReader.accept(Lorg/eclipse/persistence/internal/libraries/asm/ClassVisitor;[Lorg/eclipse/persistence/internal/libraries/asm/Attribute;Z)V
```

My maven dependency list shows:

- asm-3.1.jar
- jersey-moxy-1.15.jar
- org.eclipse.persistence.asm-2.3.2.jar

if i remove jersey-moxy 1.15 from the dependency the problem goes away but then I can't use the extra MOXy features.

If exclude the org.eclipse.persistence.asm dependency i get:

```
Internal Exception: java.lang.SecurityException: class "org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.factories.SessionManager"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
```

What would be a solution to this situation?

Comment: try to use [maven-duplicate-finder-plugin](https://github.com/ning/maven-duplicate-finder-plugin) to detect duplicates in your WAR, maybe will help

Answer (score 1):

This issue isn't the same as [Compatibility Issue of ASM 3.1 and HIbernate and JAX-RS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/969693/compatibility-issue-of-asm-3-1-and-hibernate-and-jax-rs).  [**EclipseLink**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/) specifically ships a repackaged version of ASM to specifically avoid this issue.

I'm not familiar with the `jersey-moxy-1.15.jar` (could you provide additional info on this one?).  MOXy requires the following bundles:

- org.eclipse.persistence.moxy_2.4.1.v20121003-ad44345.jar
- org.eclipse.persistence.core_2.4.1.v20121003-ad44345.jar
- org.eclipse.persistence.asm_3.3.1.v201206041142.jar

If you are using MOXy for JSON binding (see http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/05/moxy-as-your-jax-rs-json-provider.html), then you also require the following bundle:

- org.eclipse.persistence.antlr_3.2.0.v201206041011.jar

Comment: I'd love to accept this answer but so far i could not get MOXy to work. I tried several times but there have always been strange incomprehensible issues. I'll post when I start another try.